# How to resume option to use my course in SCORM LMS?

Tags: flash, scorm1.2, canvas-lms

i am creating one course in flash CS 5.5 and published that course in Learning management system(LMS) and track that course score for slides.but i need to use resume option that The learner is able to navigate through the course (it is 15 pages.) Some have been able to complete it while others can't. 
If they stop part way through (say at page 7) and exit the course, they are asked "Would you like to resume where you left off?"
We click "Yes" and the course opens again but not at page 7.Its start 1 page.

Comment: This articulate?  Believe they used a Flash cookie to store the resume capability.  But you also have the ability to store the cmi.core.lesson_location and pull it back up without the prompt hack.

Answer (score 0):

Use an array to hold position of your pages.

```
var Pages:Array = new Array();
```

whenever user clicked the NEXT use Push function an add the result to array;

```
Pages.push(result);
```

when users want to continue you just get length of the array and continue from that page.